# InstaPy оставление комментария определенной публикации

Tags: python

С помощью instapy авторизовался в instagram. Задача оставить комментарий для определенного фото. урл фото известен, но не смог понять. Заранее спасибо

```
from instapy import InstaPy

session = InstaPy(username="<your_username>", password="<your_password>")
session.login()
session.set_do_comment(True, percentage=50)
session.set_comments(["Nice!", "Sweet!", "Beautiful :heart_eyes:"])
session.set_quota_supervisor(enabled=True, peak_comments_daily=240, peak_comments_hourly=21)
session.end()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из официальной [документации по InstaPy](https://instapy.org/actions/#interact-on-posts-at-given-urls):

> Like, comment, follow on the post in the links provided, also can
> interact the owner of the post

```
session.interact_by_URL(urls=["some/URL/1", "some/URL/2" "other/URL"], randomize=True, interact=True)
```

Не советую вам использовать InstaPy для комментирования всего лишь одной или нескольких фото. Этот модуль был сделан для автоматизации аккаунтов, создания спам-ботов. Лучше используйте что-то наподобие **Selenium**.

[Хороший видео-туториал](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CGrfU_HOlcs) по автоматизации комментирования конкретных постов.